# Angular Typeahead: Convert value to number on the fly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Assuming I have the following data which i get from the server using

```
$scope.users= UserResource.query();
//$scope.users= [{id: "1", name: "John"}, {id:"2", name: "Tom"}]
```

Is it possible to make typeahead bind to the NUMBER id instead of the STRING id?
For example, I want $scope.person.id to be *1* instead of *"1"* so I don't get any complaint from the angular when I select a value. Right now, because id is of type string, my number field gets this error: **Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `1` to be a number**

Something like this:

```
<input ng-model="person.id class="form-control" type="number" typeahead="parseInt(user.id) as user.name for user in users | filter:$viewValue" />
```

The above doesn't work, and so does the following:

```
<input ng-model="person.id class="form-control" type="number" typeahead="user.id as user.name for user in users | filter: number | filter:$viewValue" />
```

P.S. Of course I don't need any client side validation for the id field. This is just a quick 30 secs example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Would replacing `type=number` with `type=text pattern="\d+"` be an option?"

Comment: Yes, it's a great option i never realized! Will be great if you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter for this and use it:

```
user.id as user.name for user in (users | stringToId:'user.id')
```